# do try in beginSheetModalForWindow

Tags: swift, error-handling, swift2

In Swift 2.0, If I do the following:

```
panel.beginSheetModalForWindow(self.view.window!) { (result) in

  switch result {
  // Save was selected
  case NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton:
    self.writeFile(fileString, fileURL: panel.URL!)
    // something else was selected
  default:
    break
  }
}
```

With a function as follows, it compiles and works.

```
  func writeFile(fileString: String, fileURL: NSURL) {
    do {
      try fileString.writeToURL(fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    } catch let error as NSError {
      fatalError("Error writing to file - \(error)")
    }
  }
```

BUT, if I combine the two like this:

```
panel.beginSheetModalForWindow(self.view.window!) { (result) in
  switch result {
  // Save was selected
  case NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton:
    do {
      try fileString.writeToURL(fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    } catch let error as NSError {
      fatalError("Error writing to file - \(error)")
    }
    // something else was selected
  default:
    break
  }
}
```

It won't compile. I receive a compiler error:

Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(*) throws ->*' to non-throwing function type '(Int) -> Void'

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add default catch block like so:

```
do {
      try fileString.writeToURL(fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
} catch let error as NSError {
      fatalError("Error writing to file - \(error)")
} catch {

}
```

http://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-error-handling-try-catch

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer (on the new Apple Developer forums).

If you do it this way it works:

```
panel.beginSheetModalForWindow(self.view.window!) { (result) in
  switch result {
  case NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton:
    // Save was selected
    do {
      try fileString.writeToURL(panel.URL!, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    } catch let error as NSError {
      fatalError("Error writing to file : \(error)")
    } catch {
      fatalError("Error")
    }
  default:
    // something else was selected
    break
  }
}
```

The problem was that the "catch" was not exhaustive which results in the throw being propagated up to the enclosing function (which doesn't "throw").